# Multiply value in a column by 100 based on the value of another column, referencing a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has the fields (columns) Account Number, Name, and Balance.
For any account numbers beginning with "100", the corresponding balance must be multiplied by 100.

The sheet name is "Data", the table name is "Data"

I am currently using the following code:

```
Sub Balance()

Worksheets("DATA").Activate
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If c.Value Like "100*" Then c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value * 100
Next c

End Sub
```

This works, but it takes a long time to run since it goes through every line. I also want a different code that would allow me to reference the column name instead of using offset, so my colleagues wouldnt have to update the code if columns are added.

I'm new to macros, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity (because I think Chris Neilsen's answer is probably the best solution) but do you have a lot of formulas in your spreadsheet which are referring to the balance?  And is Calculation set to Automatic?  If so, every time you change one of the balance values, you may be recalculating a lot of other cells.  So you may get a large speed improvement by just programatically setting Calculation to Manual at the start of your code and then setting it back to Automatic at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Looping over a range of cells is inherently slow.  It's faster for move the data to a Variant Array, process that, then move the results back to the sheet

Try this

```
Sub Balance()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat1 As Variant, dat2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
    With ws
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    dat1 = rng.Value
    dat2 = rng.Offset(, 2).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(dat1, 1)
        If dat1(i, 1) Like "100*" Then
            dat2(i, 1) = dat2(i, 1) * 100
        End If
    Next

    rng.Offset(, 2) = dat2
End Sub
```

Version to leverage a `Table`

```
Sub Balance()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim dat1 As Variant, dat2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Data")

    Set rng1 = lo.ListColumns("Account Number").DataBodyRange
    Set rng2 = lo.ListColumns("Balance").DataBodyRange
    dat1 = rng1.Value
    dat2 = rng2.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(dat1, 1)
        If dat1(i, 1) Like "100*" Then
            dat2(i, 1) = dat2(i, 1) * 100
        End If
    Next

    rng2 = dat2
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect! It is ridiculously fast. Is it possible to replace the references with table references?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CKIM as you are new here, when you get an answer that meets your needs, you should "Accept" it by clicking the tick (entirely up to you which answer, if any, you accept)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through cells or an array, use Range.Find and Range.FindNext to identify the matching cells.

```
Sub Balance()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim c As Range
Dim AccountCol As Long
Dim BalanceCol As Long
Dim LastAccountRow As Range
Dim FirstFoundCell As Range

    AccountCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Account", Rows("1:1"), 0)
    BalanceCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Balance", Rows("1:1"), 0)

    With Range(Cells(1, AccountCol), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, AccountCol))
        Set c = .Find("100", .Cells(1, AccountCol), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Set FirstFoundCell = c
            If Left(c.Value2, 3) = "100" Then
                Cells(c.Row, BalanceCol) = Cells(c.Row, BalanceCol) * 100
            End If
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Do Until c.Address = FirstFoundCell.Address
                If Left(c.Value2, 3) = "100" Then
                    Cells(c.Row, BalanceCol) = Cells(c.Row, BalanceCol) * 100
                End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If Left(c.Value2, 3) = "100" Then
                    Cells(c.Row, BalanceCol) = Cells(c.Row, BalanceCol) * 100
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This finds the first cell containing "100" in the Account column, verifies that the value found starts with 100 and multiplies Balance by 100.  It then tries to find the next cells containing "100" until the found cell matches the FirstFoundCell.

To reference a Table, simply replace the Match functions with structured references to the Table columns:

```
    AccountCol = [Table1[Account]].Column
    BalanceCol = [Table1[Balance]].Column
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop at all for this - range or array.

This code is a VBA single shot range equivalent of
 `IF(LEFT(A2,3)="100", A2*100,A2)`

*code*

```
Sub Short()
 Dim rng1 As Range
 With Sheets("data")
     Set rng1 = .Range(.[a2], .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
     rng1.Value2 = Evaluate("=IF(LEFT(" & rng1.Address & ",3)=""100""," & rng1.Address & "*100," & rng1.Address & ")")
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit faster (not tested, but pretty similar to @brettdj's answer):

```
[Data[Balance]] = [IF(LEFT(Data[Account Number],3)="100", Data[Balance]*100, Data[Balance])]
```